# -Wimplicit-function declaration in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, declaration

I dont understand how this is implicit I return an int in every function and all of them are before the main function. Honestly first time seeing this someone send me a long code to debug  and there were alot of  mistakes but why isnt this working what am I missing

```
int findString(char matrix[ROW][COLUNM],char str1[],int length){
    int left,right,top,down,result;



    left=left2_right(matrix,str1,length);-THESE 4 CALLS GIVE THE WARNINGS
    right=rigth2_left(matrix,str1,length);
    top=top_bottom(matrix,str1,length);
    down=bottom_top(matrix,str1,length);

    if(left != -1 ){result=left;}
    if(right != -1 ){result=right;}
    if(top != -1 ){result=top;}
    if(down != -1 ){result=down;}

return result;
}
```

Here is one of the functions

```
int left2_right(char matrix[ROW][COLUNM],char str1[],int length){

    int i = 0, j, counting = 0, wordcnt;
    //int length = computeLength(str1);   //returns legth of string   
    int index = -1;

    for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < COLUNM; j += 1)
        {
            if (matrix[i][j] == str1[0])
               {    counting = 0;
                for (wordcnt = 0; wordcnt < length; wordcnt++)
                {
                 if (matrix[i][j + wordcnt] == str1[wordcnt])
                 {
                    counting++;
                 }
             }

            if (counting == length)
            {
                index = (i *12) + j;
            }
        }
    }
}

return index;
}
```

Comment: Do not worry. In any case the functions are bad and should be rewritten.:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not enough that the other functions come before the `main` function.  Each function must appear before it's used in any other function.  You probably have `findString` defined before the other 4 functions which would explain the warning.

Either reorder the functions so that they're defined before they're used elsewhere, or *declare* the functions at the top of the source file so the relative ordering doesn't matter.